# i have problem in .live() is not a function

Tags: javascript, jquery, function, live

i have this code 
    jQuery(document).ready(function() {
      // ajax pagination

```
  jQuery('#nav-above a').live('click', function() {
    var link = jQuery(this).attr('href');
    jQuery('#getlooping').html('<div id="skysode-loading">Loading...<img src="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri();?>/lib/images/loader-x.gif" alt="" class="load-url" /></div>');
     jQuery('#getlooping').load(link + ' #getlooping');
    return false;
  });
});
```

but error in get jquery file and not working

this error

Uncaught TypeError: jQuery(...).live is not a function
    at HTMLDocument.

Comment: This has nothing to do with Java. I have deleted your question's Java tag and added a JavaScript tag. No sense drawing the wrong experts to your question.

Comment: [`.live()`](https://api.jquery.com/live/) was removed in 1.9. Use [`.on()`](https://api.jquery.com/on/) instead.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels I'm sorry, but my experience is minimal

Comment: @msg I have tried it and it works but only once and the second time it directs me to the link

Comment: @user4158643 your question asks about `.live` not working, not why your other code doesn't work when you use `.on`. Ask a new question if you have additional problems.   (Make sure you use `.on` and not `.one`).  Also you'll need to supply HTML as if you overwrite it with the .load the event won't exist anymore.

Comment: Alternatively, use event delegation: `$(document).on("click", "#nav-above a", function() {...`

Comment: Finally a search for "live is not a function" (the title in your question) provides a very comprehensive existing answer.

Comment: @freedomn-m thaaaaaaaaaank yoooou
this worked me 

$(document).on("click", "#nav-above a", function() {

Answer (score 0):

The `live()` function was deprecated from jQuery starting from `version 1.7`, and removed on `version 1.9`.

You have to replace it with `on()` function.

```
 jQuery(document).ready(function() { // ajax pagination
  jQuery('#nav-above a').on('click', function() {
    var link = jQuery(this).attr('href');
    jQuery('#getlooping').html('<div id="skysode-loading">Loading...<img src="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri();?>/lib/images/loader-x.gif" alt="" class="load-url" /></div>');
     jQuery('#getlooping').load(link + ' #getlooping');
    return false;
  });
});
```

Comment: @user4158643 English only please.

Comment: @freedomn-m I have tried it and it works but only once and the second time it directs me to the link

Comment: Since `.live()` is usually used to bind to dynamically-created elements, you need to use the delegation form of `.on()`, not the syntax in the answer.